# android Log.d and Toast showing strange behavior

Tags: android

hi :) i'm in my SMS receiver class, that handles the incomming sms. it normally works fine, but i'm actually trying to block some senders. i placed the blocked numbers in an **ArrayList** named **blackList**. A code segment below shows what i'm doing at end:

```
    String sender = "";
    boolean allowed = true;
        for(int i=0;i<msgs.length;i++)
        {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

            sender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

            if(BlockedNumber.blackList.contains(sender))
            {
                allowed = false;
                break;
            }

            str = "SMS From: " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += ":";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";
        }

        String numm = BlockedNumber.blackList.get(2);
        Toast.makeText(context, numm, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("CHEKK", numm);

        if(allowed == true){

            //.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

but its not works as expected. since i'm trying to display the **numm** named variable in Toast, but it still shows the only one toast, which displays the incoming sms. i've commented it, but it still shows the msg, and doesn't shows the **numm** named variable, which i'm trying to display.
secondly, Log.d is not displaying anything. its really not working.

kindly tell me 2 things:

1. kindly tell me, if there's something wrong? or anything i'm missing?
2. is my approach to blocking incomming sms from specified number is correct?

Thanks!

.......

here's my full SMS Receiver class:

```
package com.example.pingpongsmsremote;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    BlockedNumber.blackList.add("Zeeshan");
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String str = "";
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    if(bundle != null)
    {
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
    String sender = "";
    boolean allowed = true;
        for(int i=0;i<msgs.length;i++)
        {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

            sender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

            if(BlockedNumber.blackList.contains(sender))
            {
                allowed = false;
                break;
            }

            str = "SMS From: " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += ":";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";
        }

        String numm = BlockedNumber.blackList.get(0);
        Toast.makeText(context, numm, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("CHEKK", numm);

        if(allowed == true){

            //.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: If your code runs fine I'd say that `numm` is an empty string, can you check for that?

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks Tim :). this is what, i'm actually trying. to check if "numm" is empty or not, i've commented the Toast, that is displaying sms. and enabled another toast, which displays the value of numm. but it doesn't work. and still the Toast for sms is displayed. i even tried log.d, as you can see. but log.d is completely not working. its behaving like if it's not there. i even restarted the computer :P

Comment: @Zeeshan If you had commented the toast that shows the sms and you have run it, then it's no way going to display that. You might be showing toast in some other place. Post your full class code, if you can.

Comment: @Appu i've posted my full SMS receiver class, below my question, by editing. kindly check. i doubt, if my emulator is not installing the updated app. but i tried uninstalling app.